# Can I apply for Schengen visa from foreign country?

Tags: usa, online-resources, italy, schengen-visas, bangladeshi-citizens

I am travelling to Usa for a conference and my nationality is Bangladeshi. I have B1/B2 visa for USA.  Recently i also got an invitation from italy. But because of my travel date to usa is nearby i cannot apply for italian visa or Schengen visa from Bangladesh. Cause for visa application they will take my passport. So my question is, can I apply for italy visa from New York, usa. I don’t have any permanent residence id or something only the valid visa. Is it possible to apply?

Comment: Does Bangladesh allow you to have a second passport?

Comment: Many embassies allow you to take your passport while they process your application. So you can (1) submit documents for a Italian visa - they will copy your passport and give it back to you. (2) travel to USA (3) return to Bangladesh and, assuming visa is approved, visit embassy to put it in your passport.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot apply from the US as one of the requirements is:

[image]

(screenshot from the [requirements pdf](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/binaries/netherlandsandyou/documents/publications/2017/01/01/checklist-schengenvisum---tourism-en/Checklist_Schengen_visa_tourism_EN.pdf) available from the [Kingdom of the Netherlands website](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/documents/publications/2017/01/01/checklist-schengenvisum---tourism-en))

So as you have stated you do not have permanent residency in the US, your only option is to apply from Bangladesh and ask for expedited service (if applicable); or just apply once you have returned from your US trip.

Comment: As noted in the answer to the suggested duplicate, there is an exception.  Whether a consulate will actually entertain such an exception is another matter, of course, but it is likely to vary by country, so the Netherlands website isn't going to give much indication of the practice of the Italian consulate.

Comment: The exception is not for Italy, it is for all Schengen countries, so is the application form which is unified. In addition, Italy uses VFS in the US to process applications for short term visas - there are no more direct appointments and interviews as was the case previously.

Comment: The decision whether to allow the exception is made by the individual consulate, however.  Practice is likely to vary from one country to the next.

Comment: I think it is necessary to note that "legal residence" is not the same thing as "lawful permanent residence" (LPR). Short-term residence, such as that granted by B1/B2 visas, is or can be considered in principle to be legal residence.

Comment: In the screenshot, it says "a passport, visa, or residence permit". So, a visa would be considered to be proof of legal residence by Netherlands for the purpose of obtaining a visa. According to the screenshot, only a proof of legal residence is required. Nothing is mentioned about lawful permanent residence.

Comment: @phoog You are right that the consulate should make the decision if an exceptional situation justifies the processing of the application. In reality, wherever VFS is used as a proxy, VFS will refuse to accept the application.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I'm (vaguely) aware of that.  It seems therefore that "wherever VFS is used as a proxy," member states are violating article 6(2) of the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412) because of the lack of a mechanism to provide a justification for applying outside the place of residence.  Does a national of an Annex I country have any legal recourse to challenge this violation?

Comment: @Jake Every Schengen consulate in the US of which I am aware explicitly excludes those in B status from applying in the US, because B-status aliens are visitors, not residents (this, despite the fact that some B-status visitors actually can be admitted for up to one year). But they do of course process applications from other categories of nonimmigrants, such as H-1B workers and the various categories of students. Those in B status should still be able to apply through the Article 6(2) exception, but it seems that for the most part they cannot.

Comment: @Jake The B exclusion now appears to be absent from the Netherlands' information, but it surely existed in the past. In any event, this traveler cannot apply for his visa at the Netherlands consulate, and the Italian consulate [does have that exclusion](https://consnewyork.esteri.it/consolato_newyork/en/i_servizi/per_chi_si_reca_in_italia/general-information.html). They also require [a driver's license or income tax return to prove residence in the consulate's jurisdiction](https://consnewyork.esteri.it/consolato_newyork/en/i_servizi/per_chi_si_reca_in_italia/faqs.html). No info on Art. 6(2).